# How to combine list<bitmap> into single image?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I'm working on an image watermarking program that uses a DCT Transform method. I've split a single image into `List<Bitmap>` and then processed it. And now I want to combine my `List<Bitmap>` into a single image. How can I do it?

Here's my code to split image:

```
public List<Bitmap> subBlok(Image img, int blokSize)
{
    List<Bitmap> res = new List<Bitmap>();
    int jumlahKolom = img.Width / blokSize;
    int jumlahBaris = img.Height / blokSize;

    for (int i = 0; i < jumlahBaris; i++)//baris
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < jumlahKolom; j++)//kolom
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(blokSize, blokSize);

            Graphics grp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            grp.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, new Rectangle(j * blokSize, i * blokSize, blokSize, blokSize), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            res.Add(bmp);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details: what you have tried so far, any libraries that you are using etc.

Comment: Have you tried just reversing the process? Creating one bitmap that is large enough to hold all the tiles and draw each one in their correct position?

Comment: Nope, how can I do that??